# Set theory computer science

Tags: computer-science, computability

I am studying "recursion theory" and i can't understand how to study these three sets (if they are productive or creative, or even r.e.).

The three sets are the follow:
$$Z= \{ x | \phi_x(1)\uparrow \wedge \phi_x(0)\downarrow \}$$

$$W= \{ x \vert (∀z > x)(\phi_x(z) = z) \}$$

$$T= \{ \langle x,y\rangle \vert E_x=W_y \}$$

I can't find a way to reduce to $K$ or $!K$, where

$$K = \{ x | \phi_x(x)\downarrow \}.$$

---

The notation above has the following meaning:

$\phi_x(y)$ = Turing Machine with index $x$ on input $y$

$\downarrow$ = machine halt

$\uparrow$ = machine loop (never halt)

$W_x$ = the r.e. set associated to a $\phi_x$ , so $W_x = dom(\phi_x)$

$E_x$ = the range of to $\phi_x$

$!K$ = the complement of $K$.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is $\phi$? $x$? $\uparrow$? $\downarrow$?  $y$?
 $\langle x,y \rangle$? $E$? $K$? $!$? At this point I'm even skeptical I know what you mean by $0$, $1$, $z$, and $>$. You really should define your terms. And should probably ask at the [computer science stackexchange site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) rather than the math one.

Comment: @Hurkyl This is standard terminology in computability theory. The variables range over natural numbers, $\phi_x$ is the $x$th partial computable function (there is a standard encoding of Turing machines by numbers, each machine gives you a function). $\phi_x(0)\downarrow$ means that $0$ is in the domain of $\phi_x$ (or, if you wish, the Turing machine coded by $x$ eventually converges), etc.

Comment: @Hurkyl And computability is very much appropriate in this site.

Comment: @Hurkyl now i defined all concepts...

Comment: I think $E_x$ should be the *range,* not *codomain* (the codomain of $\phi_x$ is always all of $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Also, what's "$!K$"? Is that the complement of $K$?

Comment: $$ E_x = \{ y | ∃z ϕ_x(z) ↓ ∧ ϕ_x(z) = y \} $$
Yes, !K is complement of K, sorry...

Comment: @JrHowen Yup, that's the range, not the [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain). I've edited the question to improve the definitions and the language a bit.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, i hope someone will solve my problem :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer science and therefore belongs on one of the computer science forums